# Moving specific files (with exceptions) from a network path

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script in order to move files from a list I have. I'd like to create some conditions to that but I'm afraid that's where my Python knowledge fails me. I have a list of names (`AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`).

For each of those, there are six different files with six different extensions that need to be moved (`AAA.1`, `AAA.2`, `AAA.3`, `AAA.4`, `AAA.5`, `AAA.6`). Those files might be in 3 different folders. Let's suppose, either `AAA/AAA` or `BBB/IOL` or `BBB/ABC`. I want all of those files to be moved to `REAL/AAA`. The thing is, on the folder `AAA/AAA` there are some `AAAXXX.1` files that I do not want to be moved.

I'm completely lost and new to Python (basically, it's my first week :p).

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

source = os.listdir(r"\\enterprise\AAA\AAA")
destination = os.listdir(r"\\enterprise\REAL\AAA")
set = {
"AAA",
"BBB",
"CCC"
       }

for file in source:
    for x in set:
        if file.__contains__(str(x)):
            print(file)
```

1. I don't know how could I specify that `AAAXXX`, `BBBXXX` and etc shall not be moved.
2. I don't how how to insert multiple folders for searching files with conditions (If not in folder `AAA/AAA`, try `BBB/IOL` and if not `BBB/ABC`)

Comment: `if x in file: ..`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how could I specify that AAAXXX, BBBXXX and etc shall not
>   be moved.

The simplest way is something like this:

```
if 'XXX' in file:
   continue # this means skip the rest of the cycle and move to next file
```

> I don't how how to insert multiple folders for searching files with
>   conditions (If not in folder AAA/AAA, try BBB/IOL and if not BBB/ABC)

The most blunt approach would be

```
if file_name in os.listdir('first_folder'):
    # move from first
elif file_name in os.listdir('second_folder'):
    # move from second
# continue adding elif for every folder
else:
    print(f'file {file_name) is not found')
```

But I'd probably just scanned every folder and then moved everything matching given name to the destination. Although this might not be what you want if you've got duplicate names and different file contents, and you have some folder particular folder precedence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll definitely try it :)

Comment: ```for file in source:
    if 'XXX' in file:
        continue
        for file in source:
            for x in set:
                if file.__contains__(str(x)):
                    print(file)```
The strings above aren't returning me anything when it should. Any idea?